# How many islands are there?

Tags: sword-art-online-lost-song

I have been playing Sword Art Online: Lost Song for a few days now and have no idea how far through the game I am. I have beaten the first islands, referred to as the light islands, and am now on my way to a dark island. I have searched a few times and have not found anything detailing the number of islands that are available in the base game, or even DLC for that matter. Does anyone know the total number of islands in the game?

Comment: Wait, SAO is out?

Comment: @ardaozkal yes it is, it had the unfortunate release date of the week after fallout 4.

Comment: Even though we don't have nervegear yet, I still am not sure if I want to risk playing it, lol.

Comment: You already don't need nervegear to get trapped in a game.  We all know what EverQuest's nickname is.

Comment: OP - mind if I ask which console you got the game on? I picked mine up for the VITA, wasn't sure if there was a difference between it and the PS4 version. @ardaozkal this is the second SAO game that has been released.

Comment: @C-dizzle I played it on the ps4. There should be no difference between our versions by my understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think only four. There's the first Island, Desert Island, Ice Island and the 4th one is the Dark Island. I just got to the Ice Island myself.

Comment: I am at the dark island now doing the missions, I will see if it goes past this.

Comment: So I beat the game last night...Looks like I will mark you correct. There may be extra ones to come in the post game, unsure though.